# How can I edit a PDF file?

Tags: windows, pdf, editing

I received this PDF file and need to make some changes in the document, is there any great free software available for me to do this?

Comment: Related question: http://superuser.com/questions/40079/is-there-a-free-tool-which-will-let-me-type-onto-pdfs-and-then-save-or-at-least

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [PDF X-Change Viewer](http://www.docu-track.com/?product/pdfx_viewer/). Don't be fooled by the name, it's a viewer and and editor and very good for a free product.

Related question: [Is there a free tool which will let me type onto PDFs and then save, or at least print, them?](https://superuser.com/questions/40079/is-there-a-free-tool-which-will-let-me-type-onto-pdfs-and-then-save-or-at-least)

Comment: PDF X-change Viewer is not free...

Comment: @NT Yes it is free

Comment: I think the link is wrong. It points to eXPert PDF Viewer ActiveX that is not free. The link in the related question however points to the free PDF X-Change Viewer.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the link

Comment: Sadly this is not an answer to the question, annotating/commenting is not editing...

Comment: I found this tool after a long time of search. They need to do a better job on SEO.

Answer (score 5):

[OpenOffice](http://openoffice.org) with the [PDF Import Extenstion](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/pdfimport) is another (free) option.

Comment: agreed, it's great because i don't have to install a new software

Comment: It's now 14 years later. Is this method still viable?

Answer (score 2):

The "normal" answer is: purchase the paid version of Adobe Acrobat.

http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/?promoid=BPDDU

This will let you edit and delete text, remove graphics, etc.

It is also very useful for pdf markup.

Now that the "real" answer is on the table:

There are some other tools, like the Anybizsoft, Foxit, PDF X-Chante and others.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know PDF files are generated from other document formats, you should convert the PDF file to a document file of your favorite editor. You should look for a converter online which can accomplish this task for free, and yes... They can be hard to find as many companies profit from people searching for such solution.

Comment: You're correct that PDFs are usually generated from other document formats, but it's generally a one-way process. Once you've converted something to a PDF you can't easily get back to something exactly the same as the original document format. There may well be tools that can do this for some formats but it's not a universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try [PDFescape](http://www.pdfescape.com/). It's a free online tool.

Comment: PDF Escape is *extremely* insecure - they don't use SSL encryption for files or even user authentication. If you'd rather not shout your password over the wire then use [**PDF Buddy**](https://www.pdfbuddy.com) instead (see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/681865/42048)).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Foxit PDF Editor](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/editor/),it's simple and easy to use...

Comment: All versions of Foxit PhantomPDF (Express, Standard and Business) are not/no longer free.

Answer (score 0):

[**PDF Buddy**](https://www.pdfbuddy.com) is an easy and powerful online PDF editor that lets you edit up to 3 PDFs a month for free.

(Full disclosure I'm a co-founder of PDF Buddy)

Answer (score 0):

you can also try a very good alternative:

PDFzorro - PDF Editor:

http://www.PDFzorro.com

here you can edit pdf files online, add text and comment, draw lines or retangles etc..

add, delete, rotate, sort pages, merge any pdf files...

There also exist a Google Chrome-Webstore-App for GoogleDrive and a Android-App for smartphones...